# How to check Grub2 config file?

Tags: boot, configuration, grub2

When I boot my Fedora 19, I get a very brief error message when Grub2 loads. It's too quick to read, as it switches to the graphical mode almost instantly.

My idea is to test the config file.

I tried using the Grub2 CLI:

```
grub> configfile /boot/grub/grub2.cfg
```

and

```
grub> source /boot/grub/grub2.cfg
```

but nothing turns up.

The system runs fine otherwise, even "most" of the grub2.cfg seems to work, as boot proceeds normally.

I came across this error, when I tried to enable nVidia framebuffer mode in 1920x1080x24 mode, which I failed in doing so.

I'd like to test the config file, while the system is booted, and inspect error messages if possible.

*I believe the error message says something about a file not found, but again, it's that quick, that I can't be sure what it actually says*